# @Query result to DTO causes constructor error in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a query like below in my JpaRepository

```
@Query("select new com.x.airlinesystem.dto.ticket.TicketPriceDTO((select count(t) from Ticket t where t.flight=:flightId and t.ticketStatus=:ticketStatus),f.capacity,f.price) from Flight f where f.id = :flightId")
TicketPriceDTO findPriceInfo(@Param("flightId") Long flightId,
        @Param("ticketStatus") TicketStatus ticketStatus);
```

and my dto is like below;

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TicketPriceDTO implements Serializable {

    private Integer sold;
    private Integer capacity;
    private BigDecimal price;
}
```

and finally my TicketStatus enum is;

```
public enum TicketStatus {
    SOLD, RETURNED
}
```

when I compile the project, I get error like below;

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.x.airlinesystem.dto.ticket.TicketPriceDTO]. Expected arguments are: long, int, java.math.BigDecimal [select new com.x.airlinesystem.dto.ticket.TicketPriceDTO((select count(t) from com.x.airlinesystem.entity.Ticket t where t.flight=:flightId and t.ticketStatus=:ticketStatus),f.capacity,f.price) from com.x.airlinesystem.entity.Flight f where f.id = :flightId]

Answer (score 1):

Just a hunch, but does

`(select count(t) from Ticket t where t.flight=:flightId and t.ticketStatus=:ticketStatus`

return long?

Maybe it would suffice to change `private Integer sold;` to `private Long sold;` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Hi you can try to change Integer with Long

private Integer sold;
private Integer capacity;
private BigDecimal price;

//to replace with 

private Long sold;
private Integer capacity;
private BigDecimal price;

//I can see Expected arguments are: long, int, java.math.BigDecimal is looking for long type
```